# Получить список слов через карманы в регулярном выражении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В тексте есть следующая группа символов:

```
:arrow_lower_left:arrow_upper_left:black_small_square: 
или :arrow_lower_left:
```

Нужно как-то достать каждое слово без двоеточий через карманы. Пробовал следующее регулярное выражение:

```
:(?:([a-z_]+):)+
```

Но в результате сохраняется только последнее слово. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = ':arrow_lower_left:arrow_upper_left:black_small_square: ';
preg_match_all(
    '/(?<=:) # проверка на наличие двоеточия перед захватывающей скобкой
      ([a-z_]+) # захват "слова" (можно даже убрать скобки)
      (?=:) # проверка на наличие двоеточия после захватывающей скобки
     /x',
    $str,
    $found
);
var_dump($found);
```

См. также

- [Функция preg-match-all](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php)
- [Регулярные выражения. Утверждения](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

Answer (score 0):

Всё по существу и ничего лишнего:

```
$str = ':arrow_lower_left:arrow_upper_left:black_small_square:';

preg_match_all('~:\K[^:]+~', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr[0]);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'arrow_lower_left' (length=16)
  1 => string 'arrow_upper_left' (length=16)
  2 => string 'black_small_square' (length=18)
```

[Демо PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e1cbc527ef8d5ff0a35075883c0a6dc02fa9b5d5)
[Демо REGEXP](https://regex101.com/r/ZCxS3u/1)